# Org mode italic does not work with some popular fonts in Linux

Tags: org-mode, fonts

In org mode `/word/` will display the word in *italic*. For me on Linux, that works for some fonts like Liberation or DejaVu but doesn't work for others, like Monaco, Noto, Inconsolata. I think fonts were installed correctly since I can use them in other applications.

When I use Monaco on an OS X in org-mode *italic* works just fine.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Is the problem likely to do with the fonts or some org mode configuration?